# Python-bytes() vs struct.pack()

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm just curious here, but I have been using `bytes()` to convert things to bytes ever since I learned python. It was until recently that I saw `struct.pack()`. I didn't bother learning how to use it because I thought It did essentially did the same thing as `bytes()`. But it appears many people prefer to use `struct.pack()`. Why? what are the advantages of one over the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bytes()` does literally what the name implies:

> Return a new “bytes” object, which is an immutable sequence of
>   integers in the range 0 <= x < 256

`struck.pack()` does something very different:

> This module performs conversions between Python values and C structs represented as Python strings

While for some inputs these might be equivalent, they are not at all the same operation. `struct.pack()` is essentially producing a byte-string that represents a POD C-struct in memory. It's useful for serializing/deserializing data.

Answer (score 2):

They do two different things; compare `bytes(1234)` with `struct.pack("!H", 1234)`. The first just provides a <strike>4-byte string representation of the number</strike> `bytes` object with 1,234 null bytes; the second provides a two-byte string with the (big-endian) value of the integer.

(Edit: Struck out irrelevant Python 2 definition of `bytes(1234)`.)

Comment: Yes, I missed that at the time.